# How to calculate a weighted product with index and match?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-match

The following sheet shows the data I have. The main idea is to sum up every student's grade, based on a set of weighted criteria.

Cells C9:G11 are populated with data from the list A1:B4, in which every element (Excellent to Poor) is related to a value (10 to 4).

I used the following formula to calculate the value of C12 (and C13 etc.). However, it is too naive. How could this calculation be improved?

```
=INDEX($B$1:$B$4;MATCH(C9;$A$1:$A$4;0)) + INDEX($B$1:$B$4;MATCH(C10;$A$1:$A$4;0)) + INDEX($B$1:$B$4;MATCH(C11;$A$1:$A$4;0))
```

[image: Sample Excel Sheet]

UPDATE: I would like to consider the weighted calculation.

```
=INDEX($B$1:$B$4;MATCH(C9;$A$1:$A$4;0)) * B9 + INDEX($B$1:$B$4;MATCH(C10;$A$1:$A$4;0)) * B10 + INDEX($B$1:$B$4;MATCH(C11;$A$1:$A$4;0)) * B11
```

[image: Sample Excel Sheet with Weights]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF())

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF($A$1:$A$4,C$9:C$11,$B$1:$B$4))
```

[image]

---

per your update:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF($A$1:$A$4,C$9:C$11,$B$1:$B$4)*$B$9:$B$11)
```

[image]

Comment: In the UPDATE, I included the weights in the calculations. This is the main issue I face.

Comment: @IvanMachado see edit, also remember, in the future, to ask the question you want answered so we do not need to answer twice.